# Out of memory error with loading image

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I want to load an image on android

```
background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.hangmanbegin);    
background =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background,screenx,screeny,false);
```

The image is 800*1280 pixels , so if I'm correct it should use arround 3MB of memory space?
But my heap grows from 15MB to 29MB just at that phase , so no window or context leaking?

How is this explained? en what can you do about it?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bitmaps take up a lot of memory, especially for rich images like
>   photographs. For example, the camera on the Galaxy Nexus takes photos
>   up to 2592x1936 pixels (5 megapixels). If the bitmap configuration
>   used is ARGB_8888 (the default from the Android 2.3 onward) then
>   loading this image into memory takes about 19MB of memory (2592*1936*4
>   bytes), immediately exhausting the per-app limit on some devices.

from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

credit and below it a way to approach a fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127787/643500